# What to flag if no own work is visible?

Tags: support, flagging

When reviewing low quality question, a common reason for me to recomment closing is that it is not clear that OP made any effort in researching or answering the question himself. I then often take the "unclear what you're asking" flag, because in a sense I do not know where the problem is when they do not tell me what they tried.

> What is the correct flag for lazy OPs? Is this even a reason to flag? If so, could the flag options be made more clear so that I know what to choose?

Is there some way to see in beforehand what this flag will look like to the OP? It would be nice to see the *exact* message. I often saw a (probably machine generated) comment below such question that say something like "please show us your approaches", but I have no idea which action of mine will result in such a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the "off-topic" button, up will come a menu with more choices, one of which is a button whose text starts with "This question is missing context or other details:..." The further text on that button gives suggestions which are especially tailored to the "lazy OP" situation that you are concerned with.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think this is an intuitive place to hide this option?

Comment: @M.Winter It may or may not be *intuitive*, but it is the **only place** where an SE site can have a site-specific customized option. So that' why it is there. A software "feature" beyond our control :-).